# React this.props.history.push stops working when I place it in a promise. Why?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, es6-promise

When I call this function I get redirected to the page I request:

```
    submit = () => {
    if(!this.state.sell){
        this.props.history.push({pathname: "/events"})
    }
    else {
        this.props.history.push({pathname: "/stripeConnectSignUp"})
    }   
  }
```

However, when I change the function to update data in the database before redirecting, using this code:

```
submit = () => {
    if(!this.state.sell){
        this.props.history.push({pathname: "/events"})
    }
    else {
        let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
        axios.patch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/updateUser`, {name: this.state.name, token: token}).then(res => {
            this.props.history.push({pathname: "/stripeConnectSignUp"})
        }).catch(err => {  
            console.log('axios err', err)  
        })
    }
}
```

It redirects to the page I want for a split second before redirected back to the original page. There are no errors at either the front end or back end.

For completeness, this is the backend controller that I am posting data to:

```
module.exports = (req, res) => {    
    let user = jwt.verify(req.body.token, process.env.SECRET)
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id, {name: req.body.name}).then(data=>{res.send({})})
}
```

This happens regardless of if I use

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It might be due to scope of 'this'.

Comment: @Adeel He's using arrow function, so that shouldn't be an issue.